# Proof of behavior of Fourier Series at point of discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The following fact about Fourier series seems to be well known, but I'm having trouble finding a proof of it online.

> Let $f:[-\pi,\pi] \to \Bbb R$ be piecewise differentiable (i.e. differentiable except at finitely many points, at which the function might fail to be continuous). Let $S(f)$ denote the full Fourier series of $f$,
> $$
> S(f)(x) = \sum_{n = - \infty}^\infty \hat f(n) e^{inx}. \tag{1}
> $$
> The limit $S(f)(x)$ exists at all points $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$. Moreover, if $f$ has a jump-discontinuity at $x_0$, then
> $$
> S(f)(x_0) = \frac{f(x_0^+) + f(x_0^-)}{2}, \tag{2}
> $$
> where $f(x_0^+)$ and $f(x_0^-)$ denote one sided limits of $f$ at $x_0$.

My main concern is not the convergence of the series; I am chiefly interested in a justification of Equation (2) above. I have seen the "demonstration" of this phenomenon as it applies to the unit step function, but I want an argument that this should hold more generally. I'd be thrilled if someone provided a proof, but a suitable online reference would also be sufficient.

Comment: Have you seen a "demonstration" for a step function, or a "proof"?  If not a proof, can you explain the distinction?  Assuming that it is proved for a step function, can you see how to extend that proof to a cadlag function?  by, for example, noting that such a function is "nearly constant" on either side of the jump?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I've seen a proofs for the step function using a closed form for its Fourier coefficients, which simply come down to evaluate the sum at $x = 0$. Of course, this is a sufficient proof that the statement holds in one case, but it is not a proof of the general phenomenon. And no, I don't see any way to extend the proof along the lines that you recommend; I'd appreciate it if you could spell that out a bit more.

Comment: @XanderHenderson That said, now that you've brought that up, I could see how one could build these cadlag functions using a sum of a differentiable function and suitable step functions, and proceed from there. I think you've given me enough to figure out the rest

Comment: Have you looked into the Dirichlet-Dini theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Yes, but now that you mention it I see that the fact that the signum function has bounded variation is one way to see that its Fourier series converges. I'm not sure if it gives me Lemma 3, nor am I certain that lemma 3 is accurate as stated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a partial answer. To begin, I'll prove the following result.

> **Lemma 1:** Let $\sigma$ denote the signum function,
> $$
> \sigma(x) = \begin{cases}
> -1 & x < 0\\
> 0 & x = 0\\
> 1 & x > 0.
> \end{cases}
> $$
> We find that $S(\sigma)$ exists, with $S(\sigma) = \sigma$.

**Proof outline:** First, a quick note: it is easy to see that *if* $S(\sigma)$ exists, then it must hold that $S(\sigma)(0) = 0$. Indeed, the fact that $\sigma$ is an odd function ensures that each truncated Fourier series
$$
S_N(\sigma)(x) := \sum_{n=-N}^N \hat f(n)e^{inx}
$$
is itself odd. Thus, $S_N(\sigma)(0) = 0$ for all $N$, so that $\lim_{N \to \infty} S_N(\sigma)(0) = 0$.

As for proof of existence, it suffices to compute the Fourier series directly. [One finds](https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=92036) that
$$
S_N(f) = \frac 4{\pi} \sum_{n\text{ odd}, n \leq N} \frac 1n \sin\left( \frac{n x}{2}\right).
$$
At all $x$, this the above is the partial sum for a convergent alternating series. It remains to argue/show that this function converges to $\sigma(x)$ at the non-zero values of $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$.

I'll use the following facts without proof.

> **Lemma 2:** Given functions $f,g$ with convergent Fourier series, $S(f + g) = S(f) + S(g)$
>
> **Lemma 3:** If $f$ is continuous over $[-\pi,\pi]$ and differentiable except at finitely many points, then $S(f) = f$.

From there, the general result may be argued as follows. Given a suitable $f$ satisfying the hypothesis of the statement, we can build a piecewise constant function $g(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \sigma (x - x_j)$, where $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are the points at which $f$ is discontinuous and $a_j = \frac 12 (f(x_j^+) - f(x_j^-))$, such that $f - g$ is continuous. By combining the corollary of Lemma 1 and the other lemmas, one can deduce the more general result.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the Riemman-Lebesgue Lemma for integrable functions, this is easier.

> **Riemman-Lebesgue:** If $f$ is integrable in $[a,b]$, we have $\lim\int_a^b f(\theta)e^{\frac{-2\pi i n\theta}{b-a}}d\theta=0$.

For an elementary proof of the Riemman Lebesgue Lemma I would recommend the [third chapter of Stein's Fourier Analysis book](https://kryakin.site/am2/Stein-Shakarchi-1-Fourier_Analysis.pdf).

With this out of the way, let us consider a piecewise $C^1$ function $f$.  Let $D_n(x):=\sum_{n=-N}^N e^{inx}$ $=\sin((N+1/2)x)/\sin(x/2)$ be the Dirichlet Kernel. In this case, the truncated Fourier series is given by a convolution with $D_n$, namely, $S_N(f)(x)=D_n * f(x)$. This will be more useful for our purposes, because:

$$\left| \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x_o-x)D_n(x)dx-\frac{f(x_o^+)+f(x_o^{-})}{2}\right|\leq \left|\int_{-\pi}^0 (f(x_o-x)-f(x_o^{+}))D_n(x)dx\right|+\left|\int_{0}^\pi (f(x_o-x)-f(x_o^{-}))D_n(x)dx\right|$$

This inequality follows from the triangle inequality and also from an explicit computation that shows that $\int_{-\pi}^0 D_n(x)dx=\int_0^\pi D_n(x) dx=\frac{1}{2}.$ I will prove the first term can be taken to be as small as one wants:

$$ \left|\int_{-\pi}^0 (f(x_o-x)-f(x_o^{+}))D_n(x)dx\right|=\left|\int_{-\pi}^0 2\frac{(f(x_o-x)-f(x_o^{+}))}{x}\frac{\frac{x}{2}}{\sin(x/2)}\sin((N+1/2)x)dx\right|$$

If we define $g(x)=2\frac{(f(x_o-x)-f(x_o^{+}))}{x}\frac{\frac{x}{2}}{\sin(x/2)}$ to be equal to $2 f'(x_o^{+})$ at $x_o$, we gain continuity at this point. Therefore, our function is integrable. By the Riemman Lebesgue's Lemma, for any integrable function $h$:

$$\lim_N \int_{-\pi}^0 h(x)\sin(2N x)dx=\lim_N \int_{-\pi}^0 h(x)\cos(2N x)dx=0$$

Expanding $\sin((2N+1)x)$ and using the identities above, it can also be proven that:

$$\lim_N \int_{-\pi}^0 h(x)\sin((2N+1) x)dx=\lim_N \int_{-\pi}^0 h(x)\cos((2N+1) x)dx=0$$

These four identities enable us to write:

$$ \lim_N \int_{-\pi}^0 h(x)\sin(Nx)dx=\lim_N \int_{-\pi}^0 h(x)\cos(Nx)dx=0  $$

Because $g(x)\sin((N+1/2)x)=g(x) \sin(Nx)\cos(x/2)+g(x)\sin(x/2)\cos(Nx)$, we have that our first paranthesis can be made as small as we want as a corollary of the Riemman-Lebesgue Lemma:

$$\left|\int_{-\pi}^0 (f(x_o-x)-f(x_o^{+}))D_n(x)dx\right|\leq \left| \int_{-\pi}^0 g(x)\cos(x/2)\sin(Nx)dx\right| +\left| \int_{-\pi}^0 g(x)\sin(x/2)\cos(Nx)dx\right|\rightarrow 0$$